# Why Tape Backup dimension change for every program i use?

Tags: c#, backup

i'm writing a little tape writer application in C#, using class contained in this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15487/Magnetic-Tape-Data-Storage-Part-1-Tape-Drive-IO-Co

this works very well, but writes a lot more data on tape than the original file data.

Pratical example:
my test file is 160mb.
writing in a tape results in about 300mb space occupation.
enabling hardware compression it takes about 250mb.

if i read the just wrote raw data from tape i get an about 170mb file (witch is acceptable) and the backupped file always works well.

I tried with other programs, Microsoft NTBackup uses just 170mb (!!) with compression enabled, other commercial and free program uses from 200 to 300mb

But ALL the programs can read correctly the backup (same md5 and sha1 on recovered file!)

whats going on? how can i improve my application? i really can't understand this.

i add my "write" function, who uses a modded write in the class (this works only if you write a single file):

```
private void Write(string path)
{

    int BlockCounter = 0;
    int BytesRead = 0;
    Byte[] Temp = new Byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

    using (System.IO.FileStream InputStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
    {
        TapeOperator TapeOp = new TapeOperator();
        TapeOp.Load("\\\\.\\Tape0", 0);
        TapeOp.SetTapePosition(0);
        BytesRead = InputStream.Read(Temp, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        while (BytesRead > 0)
        {
            TapeOp.Write(BlockCounter, Temp);
            BlockCounter++;
            BytesRead = InputStream.Read(Temp, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        } 
        TapeOp.TapeMark(1, 1, 1); //TapeMark is a custom function to write a FileMark
        BlockCounter++;

        TapeOp.Close();
    }            

}
```

Modded write from class:

```
public void Write(long startPos, byte[] stream)
{
    m_stream.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);
    m_stream.Flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My take on it would be the block size of the tape is greater than your BUFFER_SIZE. You are not filling the tape blocks all the way.

Comment: Add this as a comment, not as an answer.

Comment: in that test i was using a single 160mb file, so block size can't help! Thank you anyway :) Looks like the final dimension is related to the number of tape writing error, and there is some way to reduce this error number software-side (like Microsoft NTBackup does..)